# Dividing real number into two sets

Tags: real-numbers

I wonder the following question:

Is there a partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $B$ satisfies $B=A+A$, namely $B=$ {$ x+y|x,y \in A $}?. Here, "partition into disjoint sets" means $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}, A\cap B=\varnothing$.

Apparently, $\mathbb{Z}$ has this kind of separation (you may take $A=${$2k+1|k\in\mathbb{Z}$},$B=${$2k|k\in\mathbb{Z}$}), and it seems to me, that due to some continuity property of $\mathbb{R}$, such separation does not exist. However, the condition ($B=A+A$) given does not tell much about $A$ and $B$ from a global viewpoint.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/#27933)").

Comment: What do you mean "separate $\Bbb{R}$"? Are you just looking for two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $B = A + A$, or are they supposed to *partition* $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Further, it this problem is from a book or class, what is the exact wording with which this problem was posed?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer. Sorry for the previous inconvenience.

Comment: "Two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $B$ satisfies $B=A+A$" 
and "$A\cup B=\mathbb{R}, A\cap B=\varnothing$" are far from been the same thing. So your "In other words" makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$A=\left( \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(-3n+1,-3n+2\right] \right)\\ \cup \left( \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[3n-2,3n-1\right) \right) $$

$$B= \left( \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(-3n-1,-3n+1\right] \right)\ \cup (-1,1) \cup\left( \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[3n-1,3n+1\right) \right)\ $$

Comment: Thanks! It seems to me that $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} [3n+1,3n+2)$, $B=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} [3n-1,3n+1)$ still satisfies?